# BST program error

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

The following code should produce a program that allows one to search for people in an address book, but I'm having some issues with the following lines of code marked.  I don't think I'm missing a class...This is odd.

I'm fairly new in java so I apologize if this is basic.

Apparently BinarySearchTree can't be resolved to a type

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class useBinarySearchTree
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BinarySearchTee<AddrEntry> addrbook = new BinarySearchTree<AddrEntry>();// error exists here
        AddrEntry inentry, tentry;
        String nameLook;
        Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String again;

        final int INORDER = 1;
        int numentries;
        int i;
        int ok;

        //  create address book from input file
        buildAddrBook(addrbook);
        do
        {

            //  prompt user for name to look up
            System.out.println("Address/Phone Lookup:\n" + "Enter name: ");
            nameLook = keybd.nextLine();
            inentry = new AddrEntry(nameLook, null, null, null);
            tentry = addrbook.get(inentry);
            if (tentry != null)
            {

                //  print the address book entry
                System.out.println("\nAddress Book Entry\n");
                System.out.println("__________________\n");
                System.out.println(tentry);
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {

                //  if the person is not in the book, see if they should be added
                System.out.println("\n" + nameLook + " not found in address book\n");
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to add this person? [y or n] => ");
                again = keybd.nextLine();
                System.out.println(again);
                if (again.equals("Y") || again.equals("y"))
                    addEntry(addrbook, keybd);
            }
            System.out.println("\nAnother Lookup? [y or n] => ");
            again = keybd.nextLine();
        }
        while (again.equals("Y") || again.equals("y"));

        //  prompt the user to see if they want to see the entire address book before exiting
        System.out.println("\nPrint the address book? [y or n] => ");
        again = keybd.nextLine();
        if (again.equals("Y") || again.equals("y"))
        {
            System.out.println();
            numentries = addrbook.reset(INORDER);
            for (i = 1; i <= numentries; i++)
            {
                tentry = addrbook.getNext(INORDER);
                System.out.println(tentry);
            }
        }
    }

    //  read entries from file and insert them into the address book
    public static void buildAddrBook (BinarySearchTree<AddrEntry> addrbook)// here as well {

    AddrEntry hold;
    String    name;
    String    street;
    String    town;
    String    phone;
    int ok = 1;

    try
    {
        FileReader freader = new FileReader("addrbook.dat");
        BufferedReader addresses = new BufferedReader(freader);

        name = addresses.readLine();
        while (name != null)
        {
            street = addresses.readLine();
            town = addresses.readLine();
            phone = addresses.readLine();
            hold = new AddrEntry(name, street, town, phone);
            addrbook.add(hold);
            name = addresses.readLine();
        }
    }

    catch(
    Exception e
    )

    {
    }
}

//  add a new entry to the address book
public static void addEntry (BinarySearchTree<AddrEntry> addrbook, Scanner keybd)//also here {

int       ok;
AddrEntry hold;
String    name;
String    street;
String    town;
String    phone;

System.out.println("\nEnter name: ");
name=keybd.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter street address: ");
street=keybd.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter town, state, and zip: ");
town=keybd.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
phone=keybd.nextLine();
hold=new

AddrEntry (name, street, town, phone);

addrbook.add(hold);
}
```

AddrEntry class

```
public class AddrEntry implements Comparable<AddrEntry> {

    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String town;
    private String phone;

    public AddrEntry() {}

    public AddrEntry(String nn, String st, String tt, String ph) {
        name = nn;
        street = st;
        town = tt;
        phone = ph;
    }

    public void setEntry(String nn, String st, String tt, String ph) {
        name = nn;
        street = st;
        town = tt;
        phone = ph;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "\n" + street + "\n" + town + "\n" + phone;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ptest) {
        if (ptest == null || !(ptest instanceof AddrEntry))
            return false;
        return this.name.equals(((AddrEntry)ptest).name) &&
                this.street.equals(((AddrEntry)ptest).street) &&
                this.town.equals(((AddrEntry)ptest).town) &&
                this.phone.equals(((AddrEntry)ptest).phone);
    }

    public int compareTo(AddrEntry ent) {
        return name.compareTo(ent.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first class doesnt compile and has a number of missing methods. Try to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you

Comment: Now I fixed almost everything but you're right.  I'm missing main methods, but I'm not sure how to go about making them.  I know HOW to make them, but I'm not sure what to do inside them. @Reimeus